# To hear voice calls from Bluetooth Speaker

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

I am able to hear MP3 songs from my Android phone using a Philips BT50 Bluetooth Speaker. However, when I make and receive calls from my Android phone the output does not comes from the Bluetooth speaker; it just directly comes from the phone's speakers.

Is there a way to hear voice calls from a Bluetooth speaker?

Comment: You can't hear call through speaker simply because there is no mic in there. The phone route calls audio to the built-in speakers instead. And your speakers specs say it support only 3 profiles: A2DP,
AVRCP

and HFP.

Comment: @esQmo_ is there still no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a Bluetooth router. There are example apps in the play store.
[BTMono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono), or [BAR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phtl.headsetaudio) are example options.

Comment: Actually, no. I have the same problem and this app does the opposite: it allows to play media on a bluetooth headset that does not support media playback.